# Using map pushes new items to the end of the array rather than pushing a new array with updated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a list of items that users can click to add an item to their array. Rather than updating the value in the array, it is pushing a new value with the same number. I am getting map from Lodash FP.

This is what I am using to map through:

`{map((item) => (<Item {...item} key={btoa(Math.random()).substring(0, 12)} />), items)}`

If I am to click on an item in the array, the result I would get is:

`0: {id: "item1", quantity: 1}
1: {id: "item1", quantity: 1}`

Yet the result I would expect from this is:

`0: {id: "item1", quantity: 2}`

**Implementation:**

Component that allows you to add an item:

```
const Product = ({add, id, title, image}) => (
  <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(id)}>
    <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.productImage}/>
    {title}
  </div>
);

export default connect(() => ({}), {add})(Product);`
```

Component that loops through the results:

```
const Cart = connect(
  () => ({}),
  {clear}
)(({items, clear, total}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Heading><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} /> Cart</Heading>
      {items.length ? <button onClick={clear}>Clear all items</button> : null }
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {/* The original version, with a randomly generated key */}
          {items.length ? map((item) =>
            (<Item {...item} key={btoa(Math.random()).substring(0, 12)} />),
          items) : <tr><td>Your cart is empty!</td></tr>}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {items.length ? <div className={styles.total}>${total}</div> : null }
    </div>);
});

export default connect((state) => {
  return {
    items: state.cart.items,
    total: reduce(
      (sum, {id, quantity}) => sum + products[id].price * quantity,
      0,
      state.cart.items
    ).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'),
  };
})(Cart);
```

Action that is being called:

```
[ADD_ITEM]: (state, {payload: id}) => ({
    ...state,
    items: [
      ...state.items,
      {id, quantity: 1},
    ],
  }),
```

Comment: Can you share your code for `onClick` ?

Comment: @agpt 

It is being used in a separate component, as such: `<div onClick={() => add(id)}>`

Which calls this action: `[ADD_ITEM]: (state, {payload: id}) => ({
    ...state,
    items: [
      ...state.items,
      {id, quantity: 1},
    ],
  }),`

Comment: It would be good and easy to understand if you could update your question with complete implementation.

Comment: @agpt my apologies, I really wanted to make it quick to understand for anybody reading it and hadn't realized that another part of it could be causing the issue. I've updated it to have the implementation and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update state via `id`, then you'll want to map through the `items` array and find the matching `id` to update the matching `quantity`. The example below utilizes React state, but is no different for `redux` reducer state (`return {...state, items: state.items.map(...etc)}`).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjmx8vw99p

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: "Apples", quantity: 1 },
      { id: "Strawberries", quantity: 1 },
      { id: "Grapes", quantity: 1 },
      { id: "Apricots", quantity: 1 }
    ]
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      // ...prevState (not needed for this example, but needed for redux)
      items: prevState.items.map(
        item =>
          id === item.id
            ? { id, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
            : { ...item }
      )
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Updating Values Inside Array</h1>
      {this.state.items.map(({ id, quantity }) => (
        <button
          style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
          key={id}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)}
        >
          {id} ({quantity})
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's happening in your code above is simply appending the array with a new object:

```
items: [
  { id: "item1", quantity: 1 },  // ...spread out previous objects in array
  { id: "item2", quantity: 1 },
  { id: "item3", quantity: 1 },
  { id: "item4", quantity: 1 },
  { id: "item1", quantity: 1 }   // add another object
]
```

Also, this:

```
export default connect(() => ({}), {add})(Product);
```

should be this:

```
export default connect(null, {add})(Product);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've been looking at what you've done since and trying to understand your solution and integrate it with mine the best I can. Something that I am having trouble understanding is how to integrate the handleClick function. For me, this is in a separate component yet in your example it's in the same component.

Comment: `button` elements use `onClick` as an event listener. For example: `onClick={this.handleButtonClick}` (this would pass back an `event` that contains a `DOM` element): https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks! I understand the event listener part of it and handling the event, the part I am having troubles understanding/implementing is trying to create the handleClick method within the Product component and being able to access the state.

Comment: When using fat arrow functions `classMethod = () => {}` the class's  `this` is already bound to the method. However, normal functions, like  `classMethod() {}` do not have access to `this` (it's undefined). To give normal functions access to `this`, you need to `bind(this)`.  For example, just how you declare state, you can declare binds:  `this.classMethod.bind(this)`. (more commonly it will be declared in a `constructor`). Now your normal functions have access to `this.props` and  `this.state` and any other `this` class methods.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, What I am having trouble understanding is the part where you suggest `return {...state, items: state.items.map(...etc)}` - where am I supposed to share the redux state? I've tried implementing this to my code and I'm not completely sure of the purpose of it or where it goes

Comment: If you're using redux, the above will go inside the reducer. If you're not familar with setting up redux, then: https://redux.js.org/basics